# What are the differences between Usage Data logging and trace logging in SharePoint2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Usage Data logging is configured @ Configure Diagnostic Logging 
and trace logging is configured @
What are the differences between Usage Data logging and trace logging in SharePoint2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trace logs or ULS logs, are the logs sharepoint creates internally for doing things. Timer jobs for example get logged here, as well as everything else to do with the standard web operations. If you need to find out what is wrong with your system look here. Exceptions should be written into these as well.

They can be administered here:

http://centraladmin/_admin/metrics.aspx

And are normally found on the server here with an extension of *.log

%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS\

Usage logs are similar to IIS logs. These are the logs for users actually going to the web site and downloading pages or documents.

The Web Analytics Service Application, parses the usage logs to make web reports similar to what Google analytics does.